# Removing special characters from a string In a Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am looking to remove special characters from a string using groovy, i'm nearly there but it is removing the white spaces that are already in place which I want to keep. I only want to remove the special characters (and not leave a whitespace). I am running the below on a PostCode L&65$$ OBH

```
def removespecialpostcodce = PostCode.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","")
log.info removespecialpostcodce
```

Currently it returns L65OBH but I am looking for it to return L65 OBH

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use below code :

```
 PostCode.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+","")
```

instead of

```
 PostCode.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","")
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove all special characters in a String you can use the invert regex character:

```
String str = "..\\.-._./-^+* ".replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-1]","");
System.out.println("str: <" + str + ">");
```

output:

```
str: <>
```

Comment: The dashes are preserved because you have a typo in your regex. There is a superfluous dash between z and 0.

Comment: thanks @jpgerdeman, i didn't notice that typo, that was so dumb, Doh ! 